# Export Use Cases out of MagicDraw

Tags: uml

I'm using MagicDraw to create some Use Case diagrams. How can I export a table with all the details about my use cases? Processing the common use case analysis process, I need a graphical use case diagram (made with MagicDraw) and a list of all use cases with some further details like a detailed description etc. Now my use cases are all created and described in MagicDraw, but how can I export those data into some table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about generating reports from UML artifacts in [this PDF document](http://www.magicdraw.com/files/manuals/beta/MagicDraw%20ReportWizard%20UserGuide.pdf). If that doesn't answer your questions, I'd email MD support.